# How to dynamic search with Criteria API in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I want to dynamic search with Criteria API in Java.

In the code I wrote, we need to write each entity in the url  bar in JSON. I don't want to write "plaka".

The URL : <**localhost:8080/api/city/query?city=Ankara&plaka=**> I want to only "city" or "plaka"

[Here we need to write each entity, even if we are going to search with only 1 entity. Type Entity and it should be empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S7KD.png)

**My code is as below. Suppose there is more than one entity, what I want to do is to search using a single entity it wants to search. As you can see in the photo, I don't want to write an entity that I don't need. can you help me what should I do?**

My code in Repository

```
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Integer> , JpaSpecificationExecutor<City> {

}
```

My code in Service

```
@Service
public class CityServiceImp implements CityService{


private static final String CITY = "city";
private static final String PLAKA = "plaka";

@Override
public List<City> findCityByNameAndPlaka(String cityName, int plaka) {
    GenericSpecification genericSpecification = new GenericSpecification<City>();
    if (!cityName.equals("_"))
        genericSpecification.add(new SearchCriteria(CITY,cityName, SearchOperation.EQUAL));
    if (plaka != -1)
        genericSpecification.add(new SearchCriteria(PLAKA,plaka, SearchOperation.EQUAL));

    return cityDao.findAll(genericSpecification);
}

@Autowired
CityRepository cityDao;
```

My code in Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/city")
public class CityController {

@Autowired
private final CityService cityService;

public CityController(CityService cityService) {
    this.cityService = cityService;


@GetMapping("/query")
public List<City> query(@RequestParam String city, @RequestParam String plaka){

    String c = city;
    int p;

    if (city.length() == 0)
        c = "_";

    if (plaka.length() == 0) {
        p = -1;
    }
    else
        p = Integer.parseInt(plaka);

    return cityService.findCityByNameAndPlaka(c,p);
}
```

My code in SearchCriteria

```
public class SearchCriteria {

private String key;
private Object value;
private SearchOperation operation;

public SearchCriteria(String key, Object value, SearchOperation operation) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.operation = operation;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public Object getValue() {
    return value;
}

public SearchOperation getOperation() {
    return operation;
}
```

My code in GenericSpecification

```
public class GenericSpecification<T> implements Specification<T> {

private List<SearchCriteria> list;

public GenericSpecification() {
    this.list = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void add(SearchCriteria criteria){
    list.add(criteria);
}

@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    for (SearchCriteria criteria : list) {
        if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN)) {
            predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(
                    root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
        } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.LESS_THAN)) {
            predicates.add(builder.lessThan(
                    root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
        } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL)) {
            predicates.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                    root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
        } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.LESS_THAN_EQUAL)) {
            predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
                    root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
        } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.NOT_EQUAL)) {
            predicates.add(builder.notEqual(
                    root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue()));
        } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.EQUAL)) {
            predicates.add(builder.equal(
                    root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue()));
        } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.MATCH)) {
            predicates.add(builder.like(
                    builder.lower(root.get(criteria.getKey())),
                    "%" + criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.MATCH_END)) {
            predicates.add(builder.like(
                    builder.lower(root.get(criteria.getKey())),
                    criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }
    }

    return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
```

My code in SearchOperation

```
public enum SearchOperation {

GREATER_THAN,
LESS_THAN,
GREATER_THAN_EQUAL,
LESS_THAN_EQUAL,
NOT_EQUAL,
EQUAL,
MATCH,
MATCH_END,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good thing about the Criteria API is that you can use the CriteriaBuilder to build complex SQL statements based on the fields that you have. You can combine multiple criteria fields using `and` and `or` statements with ease.

How I approached something similar int he past is using a `GenericDao` class that takes a `Filter` that has builders for the most common operations (equals, qualsIgnoreCase, lessThan, greaterThan and so on). I actually have something similar in an open-source project I started: https://gitlab.com/pazvanti/logaritmical/-/blob/master/app/data/dao/GenericDao.java
https://gitlab.com/pazvanti/logaritmical/-/blob/master/app/data/filter/JPAFilter.java

Next, the implicit DAO class extends this `GenericDao` and when I want to do an operation (ex: find a user with the provided username) and there I create a `Filter`.

Now, the magic is in the filter. This is the one that creates the `Predicate`.
In your request, you will receive something like this: field1=something&field2=somethingElse and so on. The value can be preceded by the '<' or '>' if you want smaller or greater and you initialize your filter with the values. If you can retrieve the parameters as a Map<String, String>, even better.

Now, for each field in the request, you create a predicate using the helper methods from the `JPAFilter` class and return he resulted `Predicate`. In the example below I assume that you don't have it as a Map, but as individual fields (it is easy to adapt the code for a Map):

```java
public class SearchFilter extends JPAFilter {
    private Optional<String> field1 = Optional.empty();
    private Optional<String> field2 = Optional.empty();

    @Override
    public Predicate getPredicate(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root root) {
        Predicate predicateField1 = field1.map(f -> equals(criteriaBuilder, root, "field1", f)).orElse(null);
        Predicate predicateField2 = field2.map(f -> equals(criteriaBuilder, root, "field2", f)).orElse(null);

        return andPredicateBuilder(criteriaBuilder, predicateField1, predicateField2);
    }
}
```

Now, I have the fields as Optional since in this case I assumed that you have them as Optional in your request mapping (Spring has this) and I know it is a bit controversial to have Optional as input params, but in this case I think it is acceptable (more on this here: https://petrepopescu.tech/2021/10/an-argument-for-using-optional-as-input-parameters/)

The way the `andPredicateBuilder()` is made is that it works properly even if one of the supplied predicates is null. Also, I made s simple mapping function, adjust to include for `<` and `>`.

Now, in your DAO class, just supply the appropriate filter:

```java
public class SearchDao extends GenericDAO {

    public List<MyEntity> search(Filter filter) {
       return get(filter);
    }

}
```

Some adjustments need to be made (this is just starter code), like an easier way to initialize the filter (and doing this inside the DAO) and making sure that that the filter can only by applied for the specified entity (probably using generics, `JPAFIlter<T>` and having `SearchFilter extends JPAFilter<MyEntity>`). Also, some error handling can be added.

One disadvantage is that the fields have to match the variable names in your entity class.